Use of non est and est
I am confused when to use non est and non in. For example Aegyptus in Europa non est. Gallia non in Africa est, Gallia est in Europa. How do you know when to put non est in the middle of the sentence or put non in and est at the end of the sentence? Can any one help.

Does this answer your question?
